# Problems with 3D object orientation during rotation (Euler Angles)

Tags: 3d, orientation

I'm currently working on adding a multi-object-selection feature for a game world editor.
I want to add a function that allows the user to rotate an object around the middle of all selected objects.

My problem is about calculating the orientation of the objects during the rotation.
It works fine on the Y-Axis (Up) by calculating the angle between the new position, the old position and the middle of the two objects.

I add the calculated value to the Y-rotation of the object and it works!

Since this was succesful i guessed that this would work without any problems on the X and Z axis aswell!
And well, it does! Except when the object is already rotated.

You'll see what i mean in this gif: https://i.imgur.com/dnzAdL0.gif

(i first rotate around the Y-axis and then around the X-axis)

It rotates by the correct amount, but around the wrong axis because the object is already rotated by 90° on the Y-axis.

How do i calculate which axis has to be rotated by which amount?

The values are in euler angles if i understood it correctly. (I'm not familar with any 3D math at all)

Comment: The gif was useful to understand what you're trying to do, and what you tried. As far as I can tell, the simplest way to deal with that problem is to use rotation matrices instead of euler angles, since you just have to multiply them in the right order and you're done, without having to care about which type of euler angles you're using. One thing that is very unclear to me however, is what the position/rotation of the multi-selection is supposed to be (the UI seems to display the parameters of the last selected object), and if you really want to display the final parameters of each object.

Comment: Yes, the UI acts like the 3D software Blender in this regard. It shows the values of the last selected object but if you change the value it will modify the whole selection group.